# Error Swipe Layout android java. When I put the application error

Tags: java, android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

Every time I put this code in my application for Android bug

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout; 

....

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            webView.reload();


        }
    } );
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you get an error, please also share it.

Comment: The application stopped working This and error.

Comment: Please copy the error you get in the logcat window, and paste it here. Without that, it is hard to tell what is going on. Could you also paste your whole activity?